# Convert JSON payload to xml with SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

**I have a controller action written using SpringBoot that handles POST requests for /greeting and returns a String response. My intention is to convert the json payload to xml and eventually hit another webservice with an xml payload. I tried the following to convert json to xml. However the xml conversion never happens. I get a JSON response.**

### GreetingController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
  public String greeting(@RequestBody final Greeting greeting) throws JsonProcessingException
  {
    final ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(greeting);
    return xml;
  }
```

### Greeting.java

```
package com.fmr.communication.delivery.stream.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

public class Greeting
{
  private long id;
  private String content;
  private JsonNode parent;

  public String getContent()
  {
    return content;
  }

  public long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public JsonNode getParent()
  {
    return parent;
  }

  public void setContent(final String content)
  {
    this.content = content;
  }

  public void setId(final long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setParent(final JsonNode parent)
  {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

}
```

### Request (Also the response I'm getting)

```
{
    "id":2,
    "content":"Hello, User!",
    "parent":{  
      "child":{  
         "header":{  
            "attrOne":"value1",
            "attrTwo":"value2"
         },
         "footer":{
            "attrOne":"value1",
            "attrTwo":"value2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Expected Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <content>Hello, User!</content>
   <id>2</id>
   <parent>
      <child>
         <footer>
            <attrOne>value1</attrOne>
            <attrTwo>value2</attrTwo>
         </footer>
         <header>
            <attrOne>value1</attrOne>
            <attrTwo>value2</attrTwo>
         </header>
      </child>
   </parent>
</root>
```

Comment: Had to instantiate XMLMapper - that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki), the correct way to do it is:

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
// to default to using "unwrapped" Lists:
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the documentation. I did not use this but it led me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this dependency in your pom, and pass 'Accept' header as 'application/xml' it will dynamically transform JSON to xml.

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your class like this:

```
package com.fmr.communication.delivery.stream.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "A")
public class Greeting
{
  private long id;
  private String content;
  private JsonNode parent;
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public String getContent()
  {
    return content;
  }
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }
  @JsonAnyGetter
  public JsonNode getParent()
  {
    return parent;
  }
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setContent(final String content)
  {
    this.content = content;
  }
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setId(final long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }
  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setParent(final JsonNode parent)
  {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Spring the default is Json since jackson is included, to override this behavior you need first to set the mediatype of your response

```
     @RequestMapping(produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
```

and also you will need to annotate your model with

```
       @JacksonXmlRootElement
```